# ICS feed imported to Google Calendar shows (12:00am) in title for all day events

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have created an ICS file and imported it into Google Calendar. It shows "all day" events in solid color blocks like it should, but it also appended (12:00am) to the beginning of the title. Is there any way to format my feed differently to prevent this from happening? Here is the code:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Nasher Museum of Art//NONSGML Events //EN
X-WR-CALNAME:Nasher Museum of Art
X-ORIGINAL-URL:http://nasher.duke.edu
X-WR-CALDESC:Nasher Museum of Art
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130818T040000Z
DTEND:20130818T040000Z
SUMMARY: The title goes here
DESCRIPTION: Some description goes here
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at another ICS feed that I exported from Google Calendar that showed all-day events correctly. Their DTSTART and DTEND timestamps had no times, just the dates as follows:

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20131229
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20131230
```

While events with times had the following format:

```
DTSTART:20131221T150000Z
DTEND:20131221T050000Z
```