# All-day events in ICS feed published incorrectly by Exchange 2010

Tags: ios, macos, exchange-server, icalendar, exchange-server-2010

I am using the calendar publishing feature of Exchange 2010 to subscribe to a shared calendar on iOS and OS X. My calendar has many all-day events. On iOS and OS X they are incorrectly displayed as 24 hour events that block the entire day:

[image: OS X Calendar application showing all-day events]

On Google Calendar they show 12.00am in the title, but otherwise Google does a better job of formatting the calendar:

[image: Google Calendar showing all-day events]

I have discovered from these posts that Exchange would seem to incorrectly export all-day events in ICS feeds:

[iCal feed all day events blank out entire day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251663/ical-feed-all-day-events-blank-out-entire-day)

[ICS feed imported to Google Calendar shows (12:00am) in title for all day events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695417/ics-feed-imported-to-google-calendar-shows-1200am-in-title-for-all-day-events)

(Alternatively, Outlook incorrectly creates all-day events on an Exchange calendar.)

One of the offending entries in the ICS produced by Exchange is this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:\n
SUMMARY:Test2
DTSTART;TZID=GMT Standard Time:20150123T000000
DTEND;TZID=GMT Standard Time:20150124T000000
UID:BC80DA81-93EF-4E89-831A-587C797949C4
CLASS:PUBLIC
PRIORITY:5
DTSTAMP:20150314T164745Z
TRANSP:OPAQUE
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SEQUENCE:0
LOCATION:Somewhere
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-APPT-SEQUENCE:0
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INSTTYPE:0
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
END:VEVENT
```

Apple and Google (unsurprisingly) ignore the MS specific instruction `X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE`. According to other posts on the subject the `DTSTART` and `DTEND` should just contain date, without a time component.

As it stands this is very frustrating and it basically makes the ICS feed impossible to use, at least on iOS and OS X. Is there a way to fix this? Or a workaround?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of the problem is not difficult. In the VEVENTs with

```
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
```

change the date-time values to only date values in the DTSTART & DTEND lines

```
DTSTART;TZID=GMT Standard Time:20150123T000000
DTEND;TZID=GMT Standard Time:20150124T000000
```

and correct the DTEND-date to the day before to this:

```
DTSTART;TZID=GMT Standard Time:20150123
DTEND;TZID=GMT Standard Time:20150123
```

Now every thing will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @HagenFrey. I can see how this would fix the problem, but how would I implement it? I want to use the Exchange internet publishing feature and I don't think I have any control over what it generates.

Comment: I must transfer the ICS-files from my inhouse webserver as an single file through a security infrastructure. I get the ICS-file with the "wget"-tool. See [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). Use this tool like that:

Comment: (Okay, I'm a newbee @ stackoverflow. continue..)

"c:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget" http://xchgn-server-url/id1xxx/calendar.ics -O %filename.ics"

This output now will converted by a little code from me. In the next comment I will give you a draft.

Comment: I use free pascal from http://www.freepascal.org/

here is my draft for version 0.99
...

oh, to many characters. I must find a other way to show my draft..

Comment: OK, that is more complicated that I had hoped but I will try it out. Thanks very much for your help @HagenFrey.